# Tracking URL Goals to an external site from a landing page

Tags: google-analytics, landing-page, goal-tracking

I have a landing page promoting an iOS app. The page is at vitogo.com. I've set up a goal for When a user clicks on the link to go to iTunes to download the app.

I set up a URL destination goal in the property for the site, and can see the goal set up in the reports section. The problem is it isn't tracking any clicks. I've had the goal set up for a while now, and it hasn't tracked anything.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: I now have two goals set up. Both URL Destinations.

1. An internal destination to /log-in
2. An external destination to http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vitogo-fitness-personal-trainer/id492292132?ls=1&mt=8

I tried setting up an event for the second url with the following tracking code on the link

`<a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vitogo-fitness-personal-trainer/id492292132?ls=1&mt=8" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'AppStore' 'Get the App']);" target="_blank" class="appstore"></a>`

I then set up the goal values for the even in Google Analytics as shown in the image below: 
[image: Google Analytics Event Tracking]

The event doesn't record anything. I'm able to set up an internal path as a goal, but can't get an external link to record any information.

Comment: Can you paste your onClick events and GA snippet into your question so we can review the code. I've posted an answer which shows how to use asynchronous events.

Comment: I updated the question. I'm trying to track clicks on a link away from my site. Bonus points for how to get the click on this link to not count as a bounce. If possible.

Comment: my answer shows how to event track a link. You just need to add the parameters for category, action, and label. I'm not sure what steps are involved to trigger those events on your page. I figure most people can get to a download page directly, from a referrer etc. So why not just setup event tracking on that single external link. Then create custom reports to see which pages of yours had the most goal conversions?

Comment: I've set up the event tracking on the above link, but no conversions are being tracked for some reason. This is what I've been having trouble with. I believe the code on the site and the settings I posted are both correct, but no conversions are being recorded. There are conversions happening, so it's not just that there is no data to track.

Comment: Are Goal Details mandatory if tracking an event as a Goal? If no and you can remove them try that. Or simply take your event tracking onclick event place it on some other link on another page and click it. Wait 10-15 minutes and check if it works. Change it's category and action to test/testing so you know event tracking is working. Is your GA code up to date? Narrow down the problem area by checking event tracking simply works.

Comment: It's started to work. It must have just taken longer than usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct onClick code for async Analytics snippets is below.

`onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/some-page']);"`

and for event tracking you would use

`onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Site wide', 'View Cart']);"`

More on event tracking here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide?hl=es

virtual pageviews and events take about 10 minutes to register in Analytics after they've fired.

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this. On the link to iTunes put this attribute `onclick=”pageTracker._trackPageview(‘/goal/downloadFromiTunes’);return true”` assuming that the name of you goal is `downloadFromiTunes`

Comment: So in Admin ... > Goals under "Goal Details" the "Goal URL" right now is "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vitogo-fitness-personal-trainer/id492292132?ls=1&mt=8" and should be what? I put that code in my site? How exactly do I format that for my link?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can't find any good support online for doing this.

Comment: You can try do two things: 1) Try to put in the input "goal URL" a 'fake' url of you site. For example `download.html` and put the above attribute in the link. 2) create a page `download.html`who redirects to the download page. The second way sounds good.

Comment: So you can't have goal URLs that point away from your site?

Comment: I think you can't do this, because you need set up the tracking account to track the goal. To help you verify that your goal URL is set up correctly, you can read the tips [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&utm_id=ad&answer=1032992).

Comment: I followed those instructions before getting here, and they didn't help.

Comment: Experiment!! try different things!! and remember, analytics isn't real time

Comment: These really are not helpful suggestions. I've spent a lot of time trying to get this working, and have been through the tutorials, FAQs, etc.

Comment: That's not the right code.